# How can I write and access files in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm making a node.js app on Heroku and I need to make an SVG file and send it to the user. I'd like to store the file somewhere in my app and be able to send the url to the user to preview. This just needs to be temporary storage. So I did this:

```
fs.writeFile('/tmp/SWBD_Label.svg', newValue, 'utf-8', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

But when I navigate to my-app.herokuapp.com/tmp/SWBD_Label.svg, the request times out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add request handler code?

Comment: Not really, company project

Comment: Well then, make sure you write correct SVG into the file and then pump the file content back to the user.